# How to transpose column into a single column based on an index in python?

Tags: python

I need help in manipulating the data

this is the data.

```
number, CODE
1003286233, DP
1003286233, PU
1003286233, IA
1003286233, RW
```

I can't find any code... only rows into column.

the output needs to be like this

```
1003286233 DP,PU,IA,RW
```

thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you structure your data more?

Comment: what did you tried until now

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide a [mcve] with sample input and output, and what you've tried so far absed on your own research

Comment: i found this, but i can't get it to work https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28491431/what-is-the-python-code-to-transpose-rows-of-data-to-columns-separated-by-commas.html

Answer (score 0):

Make a dictionary wher evalue is a list.
if you have it like in 2d array and you want to notate it short like;

```
array2d = [
[1003286233, DP],
[1003286233, PU],
[1003286233, IA],
[1003286233, RW]]
```

then do like:

```
d = {}

for line in array2d:
 d.setdefault(line[0], []).extend(line[1:])
```

Comment: the last piece of the code is.

for item in dataAgg.keys():
 print (item,',',dataAgg[item])

i need to write it to a file... i tried different ways but i have no clue to how do it.  any help will be greatly appreciated.